# What's the use of "keyfile" in Glassfish config folder?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

A really newbie question:

under glassfish->domains->domain1->config folder, there's a file named "keyfile", what is that file for? I know cacert.jks and keystore.jks are used to store certificates. But what's keyfile? does it contain all the certificate private keys?

I am using Glassfish 3.1.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stores username and (hashed) passwords for Glassfish's FileRealm.

See [this document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html#ggnca) for more information on Glassfish authentication realms.

Users can be added/removed via *asadmin* or the GF administration console.